# Move an oracle dump file to RDS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, rds

I have an oracle dump file from a 9i instance.

I want to move it to an RDS instance (oracle se 11).

What do I need in order to accomplish this? What are the steps?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to follow the below guide ?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Please include the key content in your answer in case the link goes away. If you are asking a question, please do that in a comment.